# What are Linux system libraries?

Tags: libraries

When I look around the web for information about the architecture of Linux, many articles say one component is what is known as "System Libraries" but I'm unable to find an explanation of what these are, what is their job in the system, where are they generally found and what are some examples of them.

Answer (score 4):

*System Libraries* is a vague term that might refer to all .so files
on the system but I guess it's supposed to mean libraries that are
required for a system to boot and basic shell and utilities to
run. These libraries include libc and associated libraries such as
libpthread and dynamic loader and are stored in /lib and /lib64.